# I have a 60 amp breaker do I run 8 ga or 6 ga wire? It's a larger oven.charts have me confused on max amps

Tags: wiring

I need to know what size wire and breaker is good for my oven. It's a kind of a larger one. 5 burners and oven and broiler. I have a 60 amp breaker in box but not sure what wire. I'm confused off charts I seen.

Comment: What kind of wire is it?

Comment: How many amps does the oven actually draw? What size overcurrent protection does the manufacturer say you should use?

Comment: How many kW is your range, according to its nameplate? (note, it's a *range*, not a standalone *oven*, so we need to apply NEC 220.55 here)

Comment: What brand & exact model is the range? Maybe even a link to the mfgr page.

Answer (score 3):

This is the table that matters.  I've altered it to make it more readable.  Note that Romex uses the first column.

[image]

Assuming Romex, your 60A oven will need #4 copper wire, as #6 is not large enough, as you can plainly see.

If your oven's terminals are rated for 75 degrees C and aluminum wire, #4 aluminum is possible.

It will need to be hard-wired, since there are no 60A sockets readily available. You may not use a 50A socket. NEC 210.21(B).

Comment: Great answer!!!